# New AWS RDS SQL Server Instance - Permissions for master user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have successfully created an AWS RDS SQL Server 2016 instance. I specified a master user name and password. I was able to log into that instance via SSMS using the master user name and password. I then created a database. However, it seems the master user doesn't have any permissions to do anything in that database, such as creating any schema objects. What do I have to do to have essentially db_owner permissions in the database I just created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to sound funny, but try resetting the master user password. Don't know why it works, but it worked for me with a similar problem.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.ResetPassword.html

Comment: You're right, it sounds funny. But it worked! Thank you.